# How to set admin per app in Fabric

Tags: permissions, admin, crashlytics, google-fabric

We are using Fabric with Crashlytics and have setup 1 organization with multiple apps. However there seems to be no way to set an admin user per app. Is it something I missed?

If not, do you plan to add such a feature in the future?

Having an admin per app would be beneficial if you have multiple teams in charge of their own projects and let someone from the team manage stuff like the disable / enable versions, adding service hooks, deleting members that are automatically added when the app is first created in the dashboard, enabling analytics, etc...

Currently, it seems that you can only achieve this by creating different organizations per app, but this doesn't seem to be how the system was designed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roles in Fabric are set at the organization level and there isn't currently a way to set app-level roles. What you suggested around creating new organizations for each project group is the best way to accomplish what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Any idea if such a feature is in plan or taken into consideration? I'm asking so that I wouldn't start creating organizations and after a short amount of time transition again to the other model

Comment: We're working to bring Fabric and Firebase together. Crashlytics is available in Firebase now. In Firebase, apps can be separated by Projects, with each Project having people with different roles assigned to it. This sounds like it would be the best approach for handling this and is the permissions model that will be used going forward.